# Trying to get a list of patient_ids from AWS HealthImaging data store

Tags: amazon-web-services, healthkit

I have an AWS HealthImaging datastore with several thousand images in it.

I want to get a list of all of the patient IDs for the studies that are there.

I have used postman to access the REST API and I can get a list of the data stores.  So my authorization is working correct.

But I have not been able to find a REST API call to get the list of patients in a given datastore.  Perhaps it does not exist.

I also tried crafting a query using python but kept getting errors related to the service name:  HealthImaging vs medical-imaging vs healthlake.  I'm getting errors on all of those names.

I'm willing to do the work to sort it out, but I'm trying to find the definitive names for the services and API methods to retrieve the data.

Comment: You might have some luck asking your question here also - https://repost.aws/